# -all_Load gives linker error in my project while compiling for testComplete

Tags: ios, iphone, testing, testcomplete

To test our application using testComplete i have to set `-all_load` and `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags` but while i am adding -all_load with my project then its fail to run.

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Is there any way to remove this error.

Comment: Most of time we needn't -all_load flag. Can you post more information about the error, there should be some description about what cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you added latest header files or not(for example core plot). 
check your path of the project. 
Debug the project with your device. 
Also check whether you added valid arguments armv7, arm64 and armv7s